# Refactoring similar method using a LinkedList

Tags: c#, refactoring

This is a refactoring question mainly.

I am creating some methods to go back/forward through an actions history depending on its Id/PreviousId relationship (see basic class below):

```
public class Action
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PreviousId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Background Info:**

I start off by getting a single action from the database. If the user selects 'GoBack', I need to get the previous action from the database and store it in a LinkedList. This means users can potentially revisit that same action (i.e. by going back then forward again) but by calling it from the LinkedList version rather than getting it from the database again. I don't want to initially retrieve all actions first either from the database. I have this functionality working but my GoBack() and GoForward() methods are pretty much identical.

I was hoping to see if there is a good way of refactoring this into a more generic method set rather than duplicating code? (Note - my code doesn't include the database calls to reduce reading so instead I've put dummy data into a List to act as my database).

**Class level variables I'm referencing in the methods:**

```
   //The list I'm using to pretend to be my database containing actions
   private List<Action> _actions { get; set; }

   private Action _currentAction { get; set; } 
   private LinkedList<Action> _actionLinks { get; set; }
```

**Here is my GoBack() method:**

```
   private void GoBack()
   {
       var current = _actionLinks.Find(_currentAction);

       if (current == null)
           return;

       //If we've already stored the previous action. Just point to it
       if (current.Previous != null)
       {
           _currentAction = current.Previous.Value;
           return;
       }

       //We don't have this action stored so go get it from the database and cache it in the list
       var previousAction = _actions.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == _currentAction.PreviousId);

       //There are no previous actions
       if(previousAction == null)
           return;

       _actionLinks.AddBefore(current, previousAction);

       //Now reset the current action
       _currentAction = previousAction;
   }
```

**Here is my GoForward() method:**

```
   private void GoForward()
   {
       var current = _actionLinks.Find(_currentAction);

       if (current == null)
           return;

       //If we've already stored the next action. Just point to it
       if (current.Next != null)
       {
           _currentAction = current.Next.Value;
           return;
       }

       //We don't have this action stored so go get it from the database and cache it in the list
       var nextAction = _actions.FirstOrDefault(i => i.PreviousId == _currentAction.Id);

       //There are no further actions
       if (nextAction == null)
           return;

       _actionLinks.AddAfter(current, nextAction);

       //Now reset the current action
       _currentAction = nextAction;
   }
```

If you want to compile the code. I've added in my Constructor and BuildData method I'm using to test this:

**Constructor:**

```
   public LinkListTest()
   {
       _actionLinks = new LinkedList<Action>();
       _actions = new List<Action>();
       BuildData();

       //Just set current to the latest action id
       _currentAction = _actions.First(i => i.Id == 6);

       //Add it to the linkedlist
       _actionLinks.AddFirst(_currentAction);

       //Start navigating as a user would
       GoBack();
       GoBack();
       GoForward();
       GoBack();
       GoForward();
       GoBack();
       GoBack();
   }
```

**BuildData method:**

```
   private void BuildData()
   {
       for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
       {
           var action = new Action();
           action.Id = i;
           if (i != 0)
               action.PreviousId = i - 1;
           else
               action.PreviousId = -1;

           action.Title = string.Format("Action {0}", i);

           _actions.Add(action);
       }
   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to de-duplicate some of the logic here is to use the visitor pattern.

```
    using ActionListAction = System.Action<System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<Package.Action>, System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<Package.Action> ,Package.Action>;

    ...

    private void GoBack()
    {
        Move(new BackwordVisitor());
    }

    private void GoForward()
    {
        Move(new ForwardVisitor());
    }

    private void Move(DirectionVisitor direction)
    {
        var current = _actionLinks.Find(_currentAction);

        if (current == null)
            return;

        var node = direction.Pointer(current);
        if (node != null)
        {
            _currentAction = node.Value;
            return;
        }

        var action = _actions.FirstOrDefault(i => direction.NextSelector(i, _currentAction));

        //There are no further actions
        if (action == null)
            return;

        direction.Add(_actionLinks, current, action);

        _currentAction = action;           
    }

    private abstract class DirectionVisitor
    {
        public Func<LinkedListNode<Action>, LinkedListNode<Action>> Pointer { protected set; get; }
        public Func<Action, Action, bool> NextSelector { protected set; get; }
        public ActionListAction Add { protected set; get; }  
    }

    private class ForwardVisitor : DirectionVisitor
    {
        public Forward()
        {
            Pointer = n => n.Next;
            NextSelector = (action, current) => action.PreviousId == current.Id;
            Add = (list, current, node) => list.AddAfter(current, node);
        }   
    }

    private class BackwordVisitor : DirectionVisitor
    {
        public Backword()
        {
            Pointer = n => n.Previous;
            NextSelector = (action, current) => action.Id == current.PreviousId;
            Add = (list, current, node) => list.AddBefore(current, node);
        }            
    }
```

Since there are only two options for moving through the list, this may be overkill for this particular scenario.  Passing an enum into the Move method with the direction and using conditionals may read better.

Comment: It does appear overkill but I was genuinely interested in getting a more generic approach to the problem which you've provided. Thank you for the solution and taking the time to respond.